# How to expand the bounding box of a projected sf map plot and have the graticles still show?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geospatial, r-sf

I'm trying to plot some species occurrences on a map with bathymetric contours in the lambert equal area conical projection (leac). After some small struggle, I can get the map to display how I want it, but if I plot the contours and/or specify the view area of the map, the graticles get messed up (i.e., the longitude lines and labels disappear). I've seen a few questions about this but none of them have satisfactorily explained what to do to get it to work properly.

Here's an example showing the issue. How can I get the projected plot to display the view area I want *with* graticles and axis labels?

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.10.2, GDAL 3.4.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(marmap)
#> The legacy packages maptools, rgdal, and rgeos, underpinning this package
#> will retire shortly. Please refer to R-spatial evolution reports on
#> https://r-spatial.org/r/2023/05/15/evolution4.html for details.
#> This package is now running under evolution status 0
#> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'adehabitatMA':
#>   method                       from
#>   print.SpatialPixelsDataFrame sp  
#>   print.SpatialPixels          sp
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'marmap'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:grDevices':
#> 
#>     as.raster
library(rnaturalearth)
#> Support for Spatial objects (`sp`) will be deprecated in {rnaturalearth} and will be removed in a future release of the package. Please use `sf` objects with {rnaturalearth}. For example: `ne_download(returnclass = 'sf')`


# occurrence data
sites <- structure(list(island = structure(c(6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 6L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L), .Label = c("Kure Atoll", "Pearl and Hermes Reef", "Lisianski", 
"French Frigate Shoals", "Kauai", "Oahu", "Maui", "Hawaii Island"
), class = "factor"), island_group = c("main", "main", "main", 
"main", "main", "main", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest", 
"northwest", "northwest", "main", "main", "main", "main", "main", 
"northwest", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest", 
"main", "main", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest", 
"northwest", "northwest", "main", "main", "main", "main", "main", 
"main", "main", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest", "northwest"
), lat = c(21.28865, 21.28875, 21.28836, 21.284433, 21.26775, 
21.265817, 23.63835, 23.8061, 23.836467, 23.62792, 23.790615, 
18.96859682, 19.03821667, 22.16405324, 21.8897, 22.1668, 28.38238, 
28.41678, 26.004283, 25.94462, 26.07841509, 20.76226207, 21.41212947, 
27.78543745, 27.785833, 27.753133, 23.6369, 23.7924, 23.83517, 
20.26824, 19.24436, 19.48638, 19.06071, 21.30557, 21.47971, 21.28838, 
27.78237, 27.86691, 27.9405, 27.79317), lon = c(-157.86542, -157.86555, 
-157.8656, -157.868683, -157.848867, -157.851617, -166.18005, 
-166.230633, -166.266833, -166.13538, -166.232022, -155.730732, 
-155.88255, -159.298801, -159.6088, -159.68, -178.32452, -178.37842, 
-173.994028, -173.95361, -173.9970114, -155.9797715, -157.7097973, 
-175.8235427, -175.780283, -175.948767, -166.18527, -166.2538, 
-166.11679, -155.86038, -155.90028, -154.81766, -155.55237, -158.12621, 
-157.783, -157.86536, -175.88194, -175.73351, -175.86172, -175.9971
), geometry = structure(list(structure(c(-157.86542, 21.28865
), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.86555, 
21.28875), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.8656, 
21.28836), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.868683, 
21.284433), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.848867, 
21.26775), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.851617, 
21.265817), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.18005, 
23.63835), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.230633, 
23.8061), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.266833, 
23.836467), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.13538, 
23.62792), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.232022, 
23.790615), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-155.730732, 
18.96859682), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-155.88255, 
19.03821667), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-159.298801, 
22.16405324), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-159.6088, 
21.8897), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-159.68, 
22.1668), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-178.32452, 
28.38238), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-178.37842, 
28.41678), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-173.994028, 
26.004283), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-173.95361, 
25.94462), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-173.9970114, 
26.07841509), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-155.9797715, 
20.76226207), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.7097973, 
21.41212947), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.8235427, 
27.78543745), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.780283, 
27.785833), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.948767, 
27.753133), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.18527, 
23.6369), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.2538, 
23.7924), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-166.11679, 
23.83517), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-155.86038, 
20.26824), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-155.90028, 
19.24436), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-154.81766, 
19.48638), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-155.55237, 
19.06071), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-158.12621, 
21.30557), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.783, 
21.47971), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-157.86536, 
21.28838), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.88194, 
27.78237), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.73351, 
27.86691), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.86172, 
27.9405), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg")), structure(c(-175.9971, 
27.79317), class = c("XY", "POINT", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, precision = 0, crs = structure(list(
input = "EPSG:4326", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    ENSEMBLE[\"World Geodetic System 1984 ensemble\",\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (Transit)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G730)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G873)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1150)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1674)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G1762)\"],\n        MEMBER[\"World Geodetic System 1984 (G2139)\"],\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]],\n        ENSEMBLEACCURACY[2.0]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic latitude (Lat)\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"geodetic longitude (Lon)\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    USAGE[\n        SCOPE[\"Horizontal component of 3D system.\"],\n        AREA[\"World.\"],\n        BBOX[-90,-180,90,180]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), bbox = structure(c(xmin = -178.37842, 
ymin = 18.96859682, xmax = -154.81766, ymax = 28.41678), class = "bbox"), class = c("sfc_POINT", 
"sfc"))), row.names = c(NA, 40L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(island = NA_integer_, 
island_group = NA_integer_, lat = NA_integer_, lon = NA_integer_
), class = "factor", .Label = c("constant", "aggregate", "identity"
)), class = c("sf", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

# quickly transform a bounding box
trans_box <- function(b,crs) {
  box_before <- st_sfc(
    st_point(b[c(1,2)]),
    st_point(b[c(3,4)]),
    crs=4326
  )
  box_before %>%
    st_transform(crs) %>%
    st_bbox()
}


# this is the area I want to show: the occurrence points with a 50km buffer around them
box_before <- st_bbox(st_buffer(sites,units::as_units(50,"km")))
# get bathymetry data for the bounding box
bath <- getNOAA.bathy(lon1 = box_before[1], lon2 = box_before[3], lat1 = box_before[2], lat2 = box_before[4], resolution = 5) 
#> Querying NOAA database ...
#> This may take seconds to minutes, depending on grid size
#> Building bathy matrix ...

# proj4 string to project to leac
transformer <- str_glue("+proj=leac +lat_1={box_before[2]} +lat_2={box_before[4]} +lon_0={mean(box_before[c(1,3)])}")

# get hawawii outlines
hawaii <- ne_states("united states of america",returnclass = "sf") %>%
  filter(name == "Hawaii") 

# this isn't necessary for WGS84, but it was for the leac
# stuff, so I reused it here
bath_latlon <- as.raster(bath) %>% 
  as.bathy() %>% 
  as.xyz() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  drop_na(V3)

# this projects the contours
bath_proj <- as.raster(bath) %>% 
  raster::projectRaster(crs = transformer) %>% 
  as.bathy() %>% 
  as.xyz() %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  drop_na(V3)
  
# plot the untransformed map data
# it displays appropriately with all lines and ticks
ggplot() + 
  geom_contour(data=bath_latlon,mapping=aes(x=V1,y=V2,z = V3),  color="#eeeeee") +
  geom_sf(data=hawaii) + 
  geom_sf(data=sites) + 
  coord_sf(xlim=box_before[c(1,3)],ylim=box_before[c(2,4)],expand=FALSE) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# get the projected bounding box
box_after <- box_before %>%
  trans_box(transformer)

# now plot the projected version
# the longitude lines and labels are gone
ggplot() + 
  geom_contour(data=bath_proj,mapping=aes(x=V1,y=V2,z = V3),  color="#eeeeee") +
  geom_sf(data=hawaii %>% st_transform(transformer)) + 
  geom_sf(data=sites %>% st_transform(transformer)) + 
  coord_sf(xlim=box_after[c(1,3)],ylim=box_after[c(2,4)]) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# if we ditch the contours and the coord_sf call, they come back
ggplot() + 
  # geom_contour(data=bath_proj,mapping=aes(x=V1,y=V2,z = V3),  color="#eeeeee") +
  geom_sf(data=hawaii %>% st_transform(transformer)) + 
  geom_sf(data=sites %>% st_transform(transformer)) + 
  # coord_sf(xlim=box_after[c(1,3)],ylim=box_after[c(2,4)]) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-07-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is specify the x axis breaks:

```r
ggplot() + 
  geom_contour(data=bath_proj,mapping=aes(x=V1,y=V2,z = V3),  color="#eeeeee") +
  geom_sf(data=hawaii %>% st_transform(transformer)) + 
  geom_sf(data=sites %>% st_transform(transformer)) + 
  coord_sf(xlim=box_after[c(1,3)],ylim=box_after[c(2,4)]) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = -seq(180, 155, -5)) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]